# Google DataFlow/Python: Import errors with save_main_session and custom modules in __main__

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Could somebody please clarify the expected behavior when using `save_main_session` and custom modules imported in `__main__`. My DataFlow pipeline imports 2 non-standard modules - one via `requirements.txt` and another one via `setup_file`. Unless I move the imports into the functions where they get used I keep getting import/pickling errors. Sample error is below. From the documentation, I assumed that setting `save_main_session` would help to solve this problem, but it does not (see error below). So I wonder if I missed something or this behavior is by design. The same import works fine when placed into a function.

Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named jmespath
```

Answer (score 8):

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#how-do-i-handle-nameerrors https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

When to use `--save_main_session`:

> you can set the `--save_main_session` pipeline option to `True`. This will cause the state of the global namespace to be pickled and loaded on the Cloud Dataflow worker

The setup that best works for me is having a `dataflow_launcher.py` sitting at the project root with your `setup.py`. The only thing it does is import your pipeline file and launch it. Use `setup.py` to handle all your dependencies. This is the best example I've found so far.

https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset

Comment: thank you for sharing this method. I will try to adapt it to the multiple pipelines that I have. Still curious if `--save_main_session` is supposed to fix the problem with custom modules in `__main__`. In my case, it does not help when there are custom modules in `__main__`.

Answer (score 2):

In particular, --save_main_session fails if your DoFn has an `__init__` using super. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6158.